# VBScript LDAP: Is there a way to query for physicalDeliveryOfficeName using the email address in Active Directory?

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, ldap

I'm attempting to utilize [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) to connect pull the `physicalDeliveryOfficeName` attribute in [Active Directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) by providing the email address.

I know how to do it with a common name like the following:

```
Set MyUser = GetObject ("LDAP://cn=" & uname & ",ou=" & strname & ",DC=bobdom,DC=net")
```

However only the email address is available.  How to do this? I've even tried

```
Set MyUser = GetObject ("LDAP://mail=" & uname & ",ou=" & strname & ",DC=bobdom,DC=net")
```

and that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up writing the following:

```
Function getOffice (strname, uname) 

strEmail = uname
WScript.Echo "email: " & strEmail 
Dim objRoot : Set objRoot = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
Dim objDomain : Set objDomain = GetObject("LDAP://" & objRoot.Get("defaultNamingContext"))
Dim cn : Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim cmd : Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
cn.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT physicalDeliveryOfficeName FROM '" & objDomain.ADsPath & "' WHERE mail='" & strEmail & "'"
cmd.Properties("Page Size") = 1
cmd.Properties("Timeout") = 300
cmd.Properties("Searchscope") = ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE

Dim objRS : Set objRS = cmd.Execute
    If IsNull(objRS.Fields(0)) = TRUE Then 
        getOffice = "BLANK"
    Else 
    getOffice = objRS.Fields(0)
    WScript.Echo getOffice 
    End If 


Set objRS = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
Set objDomain = Nothing
Set objRoot = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

If using an [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) query (not sure if you need the server name in there in your case):

```
<LDAP://SERVERNAME/DC=bobdom,DC=net>;(&(objectClass=user)(mail=mike.spencer@kenblanchard.com));
```

Trying it out in my own environment, it looks like this (with a couple things genericized):

```
<LDAP://SERVERNAME/DC=bobdom,DC=net>;(&(mail=email@company.com));name,mail,member,description,memberOf,userParameters,userAccountControl,whenCreated,CN;subTreeCount=1
```

And the whole batch looks like this (in ASP; if done in a .vbs file you'll need to change the `Server.CreateObject` to just `CreateObject`... I think).

```
Set oCon        = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
oCon.Provider   = "ADsDSOObject"
oCon.Open "ADProvider", "ADUsername", "ADPassword"

Set oCmd        = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set oCmd.ActiveConnection = oCon

sQuery = "<LDAP://SERVERNAME/DC=bobdom,DC=net>;(&(mail=email@company.com));name,distinguishedName,physicalDeliveryOfficeName;subTreeCount=1>"

oCmd.CommandText = sQuery
Set ADRecordSet = oCmd.Execute
```

You may need to fiddle with `subTreeCount`.